# if statement toggle div else hide div broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
  click: function(event, data) {
    $('#clicked-state')
        .text('You clicked: '+data.name);
         if (data.name == "VA") {
           $('#va').toggle();
        }
          else {
            $('#va').style.display = 'none';
        }
  }
});
```

I have the above, the idea is if a different state is clicked, div id `VA` will hide. Currently you click '`VA`' and div `VA` is toggled, but when you click a different state div `VA` still stays, it needs to `hide`!

Comment: Why not `$('#va').hide();` instead of `$('#va').style.display = 'none';`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong!

```
$('#va').style.display = 'none';
```

try

```
$('#va')[0].style.display = 'none';
```

or

```
$('#va').get(0).style.display = 'none';
```

or

```
$('#va').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
something.style.display = 'none';
```

...is the vanilla JavaScript way.

```
$('something').hide();
```

...is the jQuery way.

If you prefer the vanilla JS way, you can get the first element of the jQuery object which will allow you to use style.display, because it casts it to a DOMElement.

```
$('something')[0].style.display = 'none'; // Cast to DOMElement rather than using a jQuery object
```